# Eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation, for-loop, offline

Is there any way to get all the installed plugins in an eclipse and copy to an another eclipse instance in windows machine which is not connected to internet?

Thanks,
Madhavi

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse 3.7 has provided such capability. See its [new and noteworthy](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.7M7-201104280848/eclipse-news-M7.html).

Note: the category of **Import** has been changed from *p2* to ***Install*** in GA version of 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to eclipse installation folder and copy the contents of the plugins folder and paste it in the other eclipse's plugin folder.

Operating system has to be the same. windows-windows, 64-bit to 64 bit because there are plugins which are os specific in the same folder.

What are you trying to do exactly?